# Pandas DataFrame Display Without Dimensions

Tags: python, printing, pandas

When I print a `DataFrame` it displays the dimensions of the object (n rows by k columns) at the bottom of the printout. So, for example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [10,20,30,40,50], "B": [20, 30, 10, 40, 50], "C": [32, 234, 23, 23, 42523]})

print(df)
```

will display:

```
    A   B      C
0  10  20     32
1  20  30    234
2  30  10     23
3  40  40     23
4  50  50  42523

[5 rows x 3 columns]
```

Is there a way to turn off the display of that final line `[5 rows x 3 columns]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes! Use `pd.options.display.show_dimensions = False`:

Here is the original repr:

```
In [118]: df
Out[118]: 
    A   B      C
0  10  20     32
1  20  30    234
2  30  10     23
3  40  40     23
4  50  50  42523

[5 rows x 3 columns]
```

After setting show_dimensions = False:

```
In [119]: pd.options.display.show_dimensions = False

In [120]: df
Out[120]: 
    A   B      C
0  10  20     32
1  20  30    234
2  30  10     23
3  40  40     23
4  50  50  42523
```

See [the `pd.get_option` docstring](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.1/generated/pandas.get_option.html) (`print(pd.get_option.__doc__)` for more on all the options.

Comment: BTW, with the latest pandas, the dimensions are not shown anymore for such small dataframes. They are only shown when the dataframe output is truncated (a lot of rows/columns).

Comment: True; I got the dimension to be shown by using `pd.options.display.show_dimensions = True`.